# Deverry Reincarnations Table

Tags: character-development

A major part of Katherine Kerr's Deverry cycle is the reincarnation of the various characters across the multiple timelines involved.

Several of my copies of the books have tables of these reincarnations included, but often they focus on just a few of the timelines, the ones most explored in that book, or are limited in the characters whose souls are tracked.

Is there a full table of the reincarnations of each soul/character across all of the Deverry timelines available?

Comment: There is a table in the wiki page for the cycle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characters_in_the_Deverry_Cycle?wprov=sfla1, if that helps.....

Comment: @Alith it really does help. I'd actually started reading that page, but as there was no "incarnations" section in the ToC and the character entries were just listing strings of names I gave up before scrolling to the bottom. Thanks for the extra push.

Comment: I'll type that up as an answer @Jonita, and try to replicate the table into the body of it, then it can be easily referenced if the link goes dead ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a table that list the various incarnations of a number of the characters in the Deverry Cycle available at the [Deverry Cycle wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characters_in_the_Deverry_Cycle).

I've taken a screenshot of that table and linked it to this answer as a graphic so we can keep a record of it, should another question be asked.

[image: Deverry Characters Reincarnations table]